# How to correct this code for adding selected xml tags from one xml source into another using xpath and php class methods

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, domdocument, domxpath

I want to read the following xml and find specific xml tags by their id values , Finally i want to copy these selected tags inside another xml using php user define class methods: sample given below:

```
    <items>
       <item>
       <id>1</id>
       <name>Item-1</name>
       <price>10</price>
       </item>

       <item>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>Item-2</name>
       <price>20</price>
       </item>

       <item>
       <id>3</id>
       <name>Item-3</name>
       <price>30</price>
       </item>         
   </items>

<customer>
   <purchasedItems>
      // add the xml here for the purchased Item chosen by id values 
   </purchasedItems>
</customer>
```

If customer purchased Item-1 and Item-3, then output will be:

```
<customer>
       <purchasedItems>
          <item>
           <id>1</id>
           <name>Item-1</name>
           <price>10</price>
           </item>
           <item>
           <id>3</id>
           <name>Item-3</name>
           <price>30</price>
           </item>  
       </purchasedItems>
</customer>
```

i try with the following code which is not working :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
class Items {

    public static function addItem($purchasedItemsXml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag ,$id)
    {   
        $docSource = new DOMDocument();
        $docSource->loadXML($Items);
        $docDest = new DOMDocument();
        $docDest->loadXML($purchasedItemsXml);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($docSource);      
        $result = $xpath->query("//{$idTag}[text()='{$id}']/parent::*");        
        $result = $docDest->importNode($result->item(0), true);     
        $items = $docDest->getElementsByTagName($parentTag)->item(0);
        $items->appendChild($result);               
        echo $docDest->saveXML();             
        return ;
    }
}
```

**Updates: After changing Following code,Now Its Working Thanks to all.**

```
class purchasedItems extends Items{
     public static function  addPurchasedItems($purchasedItemsXml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $ids){ 
        $count =0;
         foreach ($ids as $id) {         
             if($count==0){
                $xml = self::addItem($purchasedItemsXml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $id);
             }
             else{
             $xml = self::addItem($xml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $id);
             } 
             $count++;

        }       
         echo $xml;

        return ;
    } 
}



$Items =  "<items>
               <item>
               <id>1</id>
               <name>Item-1</name>
               <price>10</price>
               </item>         
               <item>
               <id>2</id>
               <name>Item-2</name>
               <price>20</price>
               </item>         
               <item>
               <id>3</id>
               <name>Item-3</name>
               <price>30</price>
               </item>         
           </items>";

$purchasedItemsXml = "<customer>
                          <purchasedItems>

                          </purchasedItems>
                      </customer>";
$ids = array(1, 3);
$parentTag = 'purchasedItems';
$idTag = 'id';
purchasedItems::addPurchasedItems($purchasedItemsXml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $ids);
?>
```

as a beginner, i am sure i did some mistake, but i am now stuck at point.I want to do this using the existing given class hierarchy.please help me with this code.Thanks

Comment: $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($purchasedItemsXml);

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using SimpleXML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($purchasedItemsXml);
```

Then access like this: `echo $xml->purchasedItems->item[0]->name`;

To access children elements of a tag do this:

```
foreach($xml->purchasedItems->item as $item)
{
  echo $item->name; //and other properties like this.
  //if not sure try var_dump($item) here it will tell you.
}
```

Common mistake is to reference root element in your code, don't do that, or it won't work, you need to omit root element, in your case `customer`.

**EDIT:**  To add items, find the items like I showed above, and add them like this:

```
$item = $xml->purchasedItems->addChild('item');
$item->addChild('name', 'SimpleXML Rocks just like that');
$item->addChild('id', '3');


echo $xml->saveXML();
```

Comment: Have you read the question code? `purchasedItems` has not `item`, `item` must be added to it.

Comment: hello @Muhammed M. actually items will picked from another xml string called `$Items`  by their `id` value and then it will insert into `purchasedItems`.Thanks

Comment: got ya, give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Your “core” code is fine, but the classes construction is wrong (`parent::addItem` doesn't exist and `addPayHead` echoes one document for each added item).

This code — without classes — will work:

```
$ids = array(1, 3);
$parentTag = 'purchasedItems';
$idTag = 'id';

$docSource = new DOMDocument();
$docSource->loadXML($Items);

$docDest = new DOMDocument();
$docDest->loadXML($purchasedItemsXml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($docSource);      

foreach( $ids as $id )
{
    $query = "//{$idTag}[text()='{$id}']/parent::*";

    $result = $xpath->query( $query );
    $result = $docDest->importNode($result->item(0), true);     
    $items = $docDest->getElementsByTagName($parentTag)->item(0);
    $items->appendChild($result);               
}

echo $docDest->saveXML();
```

Comment: hi @fusion3k. But how can i do it using class?Thanks for showing me 1 typo mistake.

Comment: hi @fusion3k. Do i need to declare any class variable for xml strings to preserve the latest change?Thanks

Comment: Try for yourself... It is not so complicated! Suggestion: in class you have to return `$docDest` to append other children. Let me know if you can't find solution: in this case, I will update answer in 12 hours. Now I really have to go, I'm sorry.

Comment: instead of declare class variable, return it and then re-send it as argument.

Comment: hi @fusion3k. i try many times, but not working.i did this inside class for resend `foreach ($ids as $id) {         
    $xml = self::addItem($purchasedItemsXml, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $id);    
    $out .= $xml->saveXML();
    $xml = self::addItem($out, $Items, $parentTag, $idTag, $id);  
    
        }  
   echo $out; ` please help